# Explicitly showing that a continuous mapping of circle to disc is homotopic to the trivial mapping

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-topology

I'd like to show that any continuous mapping from a circle to a disc is homotopic to the trivial mapping. This is used in Coleman's proof that the homotopy group $ \pi ^1 ( S ^m ) $ is the trivial group (also known as why you can't ``lasso a baseketball'') he says that (see Aspect of Symmetry, pg 207),

> Define a homotopy (from a circle to a disc) by shrinking the disc to
>   its central point. You cannot lasso a basketball.

Equivalently Coleman says that any continuous mapping from a circle to a disc is the trivial mapping since you can always continuously deform the mapping to the identity. While this is somewhat intuitive since there are no topological defects, I'd like to show this explicitly using Coleman's "standard way" by deforming some mapping from $ t = 0 $ to $ t = 1 $:
\begin{equation} 
( r, \theta  )  t + ( \text{identity mapping} ) ( 1 - t ) 
\end{equation} 
(where $r$ and $\theta$ denote functions of the angle on a circle to some point on the disc).
Can somewhat clarify this point? In particular I'd like to know that the deformation that takes you from a generic mapping to the identity looks like.

Comment: You can "deform the mapping to the **identity**"? Do you mean to *a constant map*? "Identity" doesn't make sense here because you're not mapping a space to itself.

Comment: *If* you mean a constant map, then just pick any point on the disc, connect it to each point in the image of the circle by a line, then "shrink" the image of the circle along those lines. Why did you ask this question here on physics.SE (in particular with tags like topological-field-theory and instantons) and not on [math.SE]? You don't give any physical context for this statement and it's not needed, anyway.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I thought the correct phrasing was the "identity", but I don't have much experience with topology so there is a decent chance I mean "constant map".  What I really mean is deform the mapping to the map where the only element in the homotopy group is the unit element.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: With regards to why I didn't post this on Mathematics. Its because I don't follow these qualitative topological arguments (like the one you just gave) and I think its more likely a physicist would think along the same lines as I do when studying applications of topology and hopefully give me an answer I can make sense of. In particular, I'd like a to do this deformation, by defining coordinates, etc. so I can build my intuition of the topology. If I get 5 close votes I'll move it, but personally I prefer it here.

Comment: I agree with ACM. This is Mathematics.

Comment: @JeffDror You should come to [chat], perhaps. There are a bunch of people who can help you there. Also, if you'd like to really understand something about homotopy groups it's advisable you get more comfortable with abstract arguments. It is a lot more work to write out explicit homotopies in all but the simplest cases than to go with abstract arguments (*qualitative* is not the right word here, IMO).

Comment: @Danu: Thanks, I can try the chat. I definitely agree its crucial to understand abstract arguments and much more cumbersome to write out explicit homotopies. But from my experience its usually important to understand how to do something the long way, and only then learn the slick way since you get a better understanding of whats going on.

Comment: If we parametrize our circle by $\phi$ and our disc by $r$ and $\theta$, then let $(r(\phi),\theta(\phi))$ denote the original continuous map from the circle to the disc. Now simply define the homotopy as $r_t(\phi) := t \; r(\phi)$ and $\theta_t(\phi) := \theta(\phi)$. It's continuous since it is a product of continuous functions.